# Is there any way to access the current locale with React-Intl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-intl

I was wondering if there is any way to access what is the currently set locale with React-Intl?

Let's say I create this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <IntlProvider locale="en">
      <App>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

In App, I would like to do something like this, in order to access the locale that I passed to the `IntlProvider`

```
this.props.locale
```

Is there any way to do something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

## New answer - using hooks (see below for original)

```js
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
    const intl = useIntl()
    return <div>{`Current locale: ${intl.locale}`}</div>
}

export default MyComponent
```

---

## Old answer

You can get the current locale in any component of your App by simply accessing it from React Intl's "injection API":

```
import {injectIntl, intlShape} from 'react-intl';

const propTypes = {
  intl: intlShape.isRequired,
};

const MyComponent = ({intl}) => (
  <div>{`Current locale: ${intl.locale}`}</div>
);

MyComponent.propTypes = propTypes

export default injectIntl(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Almost 2yrs later and we now have a hook to do this @pierre do you want to update your answer? you can `const intl = useIntl(); console.log(intl.locale)`

Comment: Hi @Bruford , thank you for this. I would gladly update my answer, but I must admit I haven't practiced hooks yet (I am currently working on other stacks). Could you please send me the updated answer with hook?

Comment: You could even do: const {locale} = useIntl()

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to access current locale in any child component, the best way would be to read *context*, because IntlProvider is providing a context.
Define in your App or any other component the context you want to access:

```
App.contextTypes = {
    intl: PropTypes.object
};
```

Now you can read the current locale in your component like:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>{this.context.intl.locale}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `injectIntl` is a cleaner way to access the `intl` object.